Order pandas dataframe rows with custom order defined by list
I'm trying to order this dataframe in quarterly order using the list sortTo as reference to put it into a table.
import pandas as pd

# Sample DataFrame
data = {'QuarterYear': ["Q1 2024", "Q2 2024", "Q3 2023", 'Q3 2024', "Q4 2023", "Q4 2024"], 'data1': [5, 6, 2, 1, 10, 3], 'data2': [12, 4, 2, 7, 2, 9]}
sortTo = ["Q3 2023", "Q4 2023", "Q1 2024", 'Q2 2024', "Q3 2024", "Q4 2024"]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.reindex(sortTo)

I've tried re-index, sort_values to no avail. I cannot use np.sort as the quarters are not numerical.
Current output:
  QuarterYear  data1  data2
0     Q1 2024      5     12
1     Q2 2024      6      4
2     Q3 2023      2      2
3     Q3 2024      1      7
4     Q4 2023     10      2
5     Q4 2024      3      9


Related: Sort list of dates by year & quarter

Code
use key parameter for custom sorting.
out = df.sort_values(
    'QuarterYear', 
    key=lambda x: x.map({k: n for n, k in enumerate(sortTo)})
)

out:
  QuarterYear  data1  data2
2     Q3 2023      2      2
4     Q4 2023     10      2
0     Q1 2024      5     12
1     Q2 2024      6      4
3     Q3 2024      1      7
5     Q4 2024      3      9


If your data consists of years and quarters, the following code should do the sorting you need without sortTo.
out = df.sort_values(
    'QuarterYear', 
    key=lambda x: x.str.replace(r'(Q\d) (\d+)', r'\2 \1', regex=True)
)


Not sure if there is any constraint but why don't you change column to category and sort. In this case, the category are in order as expected so expected so simply .sort_values would work without need of extra list "sortTo" for sorting.
df['QuarterYear'] = df['QuarterYear'].astype("category")
df.sort_values(['QuarterYear'], ignore_index=True)


That's a good approach, but you need to define the custom order (I added an example in my answer)

I would recommend to convert your string to Quarterly Periods. Then you'll be able to sort naturally:
df['QuarterYear'] = pd.PeriodIndex(
    df['QuarterYear'].str.replace(r'(Q\d) (\d{4})', r'\2-\1', regex=True),
    freq='Q',
)

out = df.sort_values(by='QuarterYear')

Output:
  QuarterYear  data1  data2
2      2023Q3      2      2
4      2023Q4     10      2
0      2024Q1      5     12
1      2024Q2      6      4
3      2024Q3      1      7
5      2024Q4      3      9

If you insist on the custom order from a list, use a CategoricalDtype:
cat = pd.CategoricalDtype(sortTo, ordered=True)

out = df.astype({'QuarterYear': cat}).sort_values(by='QuarterYear')

Output:
  QuarterYear  data1  data2
2     Q3 2023      2      2
4     Q4 2023     10      2
0     Q1 2024      5     12
1     Q2 2024      6      4
3     Q3 2024      1      7
5     Q4 2024      3      9


You can convert 'QuarterYear' column to a categorical type with the order specified in 'sortTo'
sortTo = ["Q3 2023", "Q4 2023", "Q1 2024", 'Q2 2024', "Q3 2024", "Q4 2024"]

df['QuarterYear'] = pd.Categorical(df['QuarterYear'], categories=sortTo, ordered=True)
df_sorted = df.sort_values(by='QuarterYear')

Output
  QuarterYear  data1  data2
2     Q3 2023      2      2
4     Q4 2023     10      2
0     Q1 2024      5     12
1     Q2 2024      6      4
3     Q3 2024      1      7
5     Q4 2024      3      9

